# Rx - Reactive extensions - conditional switch from first Observable to second

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have 2 data sources: online and offline (cached). Both of them returns IObservable of object which contains 2 flags - IsSuccess and IsCached. I would like to get data from online source but only when IsSuccess=true.  If this fail I would like to get data from offline source. Additionally I want to save new data in cache for future. I am not sure how to do it best in RX.
Here is my implementation of that but I think it can be done much better

```
public IObservable<Result<SampleModel>> GetSampleModel()
    {
        IObservable<Result<SampleModel>> onlineObservable = _onlineSource.GetData<SampleModel>();
        IObservable<Result<SampleModel>> offlineObservable = _offlineSource.GetData<SampleModel>();

        var subject = new Subject<Result<SampleModel>>();

        onlineObservable.Do(async (result) =>
        {
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                await _offlineSource.CacheData(result.Data).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }).Subscribe((result) =>
        {
            if (result.IsSuccess)
            {
                subject.OnNext(result);
            }
            subject.OnCompleted();
        });

        return subject.Concat(offlineObservable).Take(1);
    }
```

Result class - wrapper for data:

```
public class Result<T>
{
    public Result(Exception exception)
    {
        Exception = exception;
    }

    public Result(T data, bool isCached = false)
    {
        IsCached = isCached;
        IsSuccess = true;
        Data = data;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; private set; }
    public bool IsCached { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation will not work reliably, because there is a race condition in there. Consider this:

```
var temp = GetSampleModel(); // #1
// Do some long operation here
temp.Subscribe(p => Console.WriteLine(p)); // #2
```

In this case, fetching data will start in #1, and if the data is received and pushed to subject before #2 executes, nothing will be printed no matter how long you wait.

Usually, you should avoid subscribing inside a function returning `IObservable` to avoid such issues. Using `Do` is also a bad smell. You could fix the code using `ReplaySubject` or `AsyncSubject`, but in such cases I generally prefer `Observable.Create`. Here is my rewrite:

```
public IObservable<SampleModel> GetSampleModel(IScheduler scheduler = null)
{
    scheduler = scheduler ?? TaskPoolScheduler.Default;
    return Observable.Create<SampleModel>(observer =>
    {
        return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (s, ct) =>
        {
            var onlineResult = await _onlineSource.GetData<SampleModel>().FirstAsync();
            if (onlineResult.IsSuccess)
            {
                observer.OnNext(onlineResult.Data);
                await _offlineSource.CacheData(onlineResult.Data);
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                var offlineResult = await _offlineSource.GetData<SampleModel>().FirstAsync();
                if (offlineResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(offlineResult.Data);
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                }
                else
                {
                    observer.OnError(new Exception("Could not receive model"));
                }
            }
            return Disposable.Empty;
        });
    });
}
```

You can see that it still isn't terribly pretty. I think that it's because you chose not to use natural Rx system of handling errors, but instead to wrap your values in `Result` type. If you alter your repository methods to [handle errors in Rx way](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#OnErrorAndOnCompleted), resulting code is much more concise. (Note that I changed your `Result` type to `MaybeCached`, and I assume that now both sources return `IObservable<SampleModel>`, which is a [cold observable](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#HotAndCold) either returning a single result or an error):

```
public class MaybeCached<T>
{
    public MaybeCached(T data, bool isCached)
    {
        IsCached = isCached;
        IsSuccess = true;
    }

    public bool IsCached { get; private set; }
    public T Data { get; private set; }
}

public IObservable<SampleModel> GetSampleModel()
{
    _onlineSource
        .GetData<SampleModel>()
        .Select(d => new MaybeCached(d, false))
        .Catch(_offlineSource
                    .GetData<SampleModel>()
                    .Select(d => new MaybeCached(d, true))
        .SelectMany(data => data.IsCached ? Observable.Return(data.Data) : _offlineSource.CacheData(data.Data).Select(_ => data.Data));
}
```

[`Catch`](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/11_AdvancedErrorHandling.html#Catch) is used here in order to obtain a conditional switch you asked for.